# Enumerate Microsoft SQL database servers on the local network, using delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

If I was using C# I could use the .net framework's [SqlDataSourceEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to discover and show a user a list of SQL Server instances on the network.

How can I do that in Delphi?

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/od/sqlservermsdeaccess/l/aa090704a.htm

Comment: I actually used Whiler's linked code. If you convert that comment to an answer and expand it a tiny bit, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done... but like I said... everything is already explained on his page and I don't want to *steal* his content :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enumerate all available Microsoft SQL Servers, you can follow this excellent tutorial:

> [Enumerating available SQL Servers. Retrieving databases on a SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907013136/http://delphi.about.com/od/sqlservermsdeaccess/l/aa090704a.htm)

Included in [Zarko](https://www.thoughtco.com/zarko-gajic-bio-1056695)'s tutorial, there's a link to [download the full source code (direct download)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150926143559/http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/code/src090704.zip) which can be useful to quickly test it and check if it fits your needs.

**Edit** Zarko Gajic's main routine is:

```
procedure ListAvailableSQLServers(Names : TStrings);
var
  RSCon: ADORecordsetConstruction;
  Rowset: IRowset;
  SourcesRowset: ISourcesRowset;
  SourcesRecordset: _Recordset;
  SourcesName, SourcesType: TField;

    function PtCreateADOObject(const ClassID: TGUID): IUnknown;
    var
      Status: HResult;
      FPUControlWord: Word;
    begin
      asm
        FNSTCW FPUControlWord
      end;
      Status := CoCreateInstance(
                  CLASS_Recordset,
                  nil,
                  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                  IUnknown,
                  Result);
      asm
        FNCLEX
        FLDCW FPUControlWord
      end;
      OleCheck(Status);
    end;
begin
  SourcesRecordset := PtCreateADOObject(CLASS_Recordset) as _Recordset;
  RSCon := SourcesRecordset as ADORecordsetConstruction;
  SourcesRowset := CreateComObject(ProgIDToClassID('SQLOLEDB Enumerator')) as ISourcesRowset;
  OleCheck(SourcesRowset.GetSourcesRowset(nil, IRowset, 0, nil, IUnknown(Rowset)));
  RSCon.Rowset := RowSet;
  with TADODataSet.Create(nil) do
  try
    Recordset := SourcesRecordset;
    SourcesName := FieldByName('SOURCES_NAME'); { do not localize }
    SourcesType := FieldByName('SOURCES_TYPE'); { do not localize }
    Names.BeginUpdate;
    try
      while not EOF do
      begin
        if (SourcesType.AsInteger = DBSOURCETYPE_DATASOURCE) and (SourcesName.AsString <> '') then
          Names.Add(SourcesName.AsString);
        Next;
      end;
    finally
      Names.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

I don't know what I can add without *lamering* what Zarko's explained.

Comment: I took the liberty of posting a core routine (a snippet from the real code) because I think that's acceptable practice here and generally on the internet. No intent here to steal from Zarko, praise be to the Zarkmeister and Uber-About-Delphi-Guy. :-)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [NetServerEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function , filtering by the `SV_TYPE_SQLSERVER` value in the servertype param, another option is use the [`SQLOLEDB Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198369%28v=sql.80%29) ADO object.

Answer (score 5):

I use this code:

```
uses ActiveX,
     ComObj,
     OleDB,
     DB,
     ADOInt,
     ADODB;

procedure ListAvailableSQLServers(Names: TStringList);
var
  RSCon: ADORecordsetConstruction;
  Rowset: IRowset;
  SourcesRowset: ISourcesRowset;
  SourcesRecordset: _Recordset;
  SourcesName, SourcesType: TField;

function PtCreateADOObject(const ClassID: TGUID): IUnknown;
var
  Status: HResult;
  FPUControlWord: Word;
begin
  asm
    FNSTCW FPUControlWord
  end;
  Status := CoCreateInstance(
              CLASS_Recordset,
              nil,
              CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
              CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
              IUnknown,
              Result);
  asm
    FNCLEX
    FLDCW FPUControlWord
  end;
  OleCheck(Status);
end;

begin
  SourcesRecordset :=
       PtCreateADOObject(CLASS_Recordset)
       as _Recordset;
  RSCon :=
       SourcesRecordset
       as ADORecordsetConstruction;
   SourcesRowset :=
       CreateComObject(ProgIDToClassID('SQLOLEDB Enumerator'))
       as ISourcesRowset;
   OleCheck(SourcesRowset.GetSourcesRowset(
            nil,
            IRowset, 0,
            nil,
            IUnknown(Rowset)));
   RSCon.Rowset := RowSet;
   with TADODataSet.Create(nil) do
   try
     Recordset := SourcesRecordset;
     SourcesName := FieldByName('SOURCES_NAME');
     SourcesType := FieldByName('SOURCES_TYPE');
     Names.BeginUpdate;
     Names.Clear;
     try
        while not EOF do
        begin
          if (SourcesType.AsInteger = DBSOURCETYPE_DATASOURCE) and
             (SourcesName.AsString <> '') then
            Names.Add(SourcesName.AsString);
          Next;
        end;
     finally
        Names.EndUpdate;
     end;
  finally
     Free;
  end;
end;




procedure GetServer();
var
  oItems: TStringList;
begin
  oItems:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    ListAvailableSQLServers(oItems);
    // To something with oItems
    ShowMessage(oItems.Text);
  finally
    oItems.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't forget to set ADODB in the uses

Comment: And a few others. (Made a valid uses clause.)