# How to enumerate MSSQL Servers from a 64-bit client app?

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I'm looking for a way of enumerating MS SQL Servers on the local network from a 64-bit Delphi application.  The method I've used thus far on 32-bit works fine but contains assembly code which won't compile on 32-bit.  I can't seem to find a way of enumerating servers from a 64-bit client.

The code that I cannot compile is this:

```
function PtCreateADOObject(const ClassID: TGUID): IUnknown;
var
  Status: HResult;
  FPUControlWord: Word;
begin
  asm
    FNSTCW FPUControlWord
  end;
  Status := CoCreateInstance(
              CLASS_Recordset,
              nil,
              CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
              IUnknown,
              Result);
  asm
    FNCLEX
    FLDCW FPUControlWord
  end;
  OleCheck(Status);
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you have and we could remove the dependency on asm

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609728/enumerate-microsoft-sql-database-servers-on-the-local-network-using-delphi

Comment: Actually the code shown in that article is what I'm currently using on 32-bit.  The two asm sections in the PtCreateADOObject function are what's causing the problem - they appear to be saving and restoring the FPU control word value around the CoCreateInstance call but I have no idea why or how to change this back into standard Pascal code.

Comment: And what is wrong with `select * from master.sys.databases`

Comment: @Toby These ASM instructions is try to prevent FPU-related exceptions as i understand. I don't think you really need it, ignoring is not a way of processing anyway, try to comment both ASM sections.

Comment: @StijnSanders That will get me a list of databases on a given server, but what I'm after is enumerating actual servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609728/enumerate-microsoft-sql-database-servers-on-the-local-network-using-delphi) adopted for x64, now it is compatible with both, x32/x64 systems.

```
uses
  ActiveX, ComObj, OleDB, DB, ADOInt, ADODB;

function CreateADOObject(const ClassID: TGUID): IUnknown;
var
  Status: HResult;
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
  FPUControlWord: Word;
{$ENDIF CPUX86}
begin

{$IFDEF CPUX86}
  asm
    FNSTCW  FPUControlWord
  end;
{$ENDIF CPUX86}
  Status := CoCreateInstance(ClassID, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Result);
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
  asm
    FNCLEX
    FLDCW FPUControlWord
  end;
{$ENDIF CPUX86}
  if (Status = REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) then
    raise Exception.Create('error')
  else
    OleCheck(Status);
end;

procedure ListAvailableSQLServers(Names: TStringList);
var
  RSCon: ADORecordsetConstruction;
  Rowset: IRowset;
  SourcesRowset: ISourcesRowset;
  SourcesRecordset: _Recordset;
  SourcesName, SourcesType: TField;
begin
  SourcesRecordset := CreateADOObject(CLASS_Recordset) as _Recordset;
  RSCon := SourcesRecordset as ADORecordsetConstruction;
   SourcesRowset := CreateComObject(ProgIDToClassID('SQLOLEDB Enumerator')) as ISourcesRowset;
   OleCheck(SourcesRowset.GetSourcesRowset(nil, IRowset, 0, nil, IUnknown(Rowset)));
   RSCon.Rowset := RowSet;
   with TADODataSet.Create(nil) do
   try
     Recordset := SourcesRecordset;
     SourcesName := FieldByName('SOURCES_NAME');
     SourcesType := FieldByName('SOURCES_TYPE');
     Names.BeginUpdate;
     Names.Clear;
     try
        while not EOF do
        begin
          if (SourcesType.AsInteger = DBSOURCETYPE_DATASOURCE) and
             (SourcesName.AsString <> '')
           then
            Names.Add(SourcesName.AsString);
          Next;
        end;
     finally
        Names.EndUpdate;
     end;
  finally
     Free;
  end;
end;

procedure GetServer;
var
  oItems: TStringList;
begin
  oItems:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    ListAvailableSQLServers(oItems);
    // To something with oItems
    ShowMessage(oItems.Text);
  finally
    oItems.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If the control state needs to be preserved under 32 bit then quite likely it needs to be under 64 bit too. And it's not hard to write this code in a clean way that does not require conditionals at this high level, or use asm. I personally am not fond of this code. I know it's the simple thing to do, but I'd rather see a more sweeping change.

Comment: @David: In Data.Win.ADODB.pas (comes with Delphi) they save it only for x32, so i guess it is not necessary for x64 mode.

Comment: Or perhaps the Emba people didn't know how to do it properly! Anyway, I don't much care either for the Emba code that you lifted into your answer.

Comment: @David I'm not too fond of the code myself, or asm sections in general but I've failed to find a cleaner or 'prettier' way of doing this thus far.

Answer (score 8):

The code that is causing you trouble simply stores and restores the floating point control state. You can write that in a cross-platform way (well, supporting x86 and x64) like this:

```
type
  TFPControlState = {$IFDEF CPUX86}Word{$ENDIF}{$IFDEF CPUX64}UInt32{$ENDIF};

function GetFPControlState: TFPControlState;
begin
  {$IFDEF CPUX86}
  Result := Get8087CW;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF CPUX64}
  Result := GetMXCSR;
  {$ENDIF}
end;

procedure SetFPControlState(const Value: TFPControlState);
begin
  {$IFDEF CPUX86}
  Set8087CW(Value);
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF CPUX64}
  SetMXCSR(Value);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

This abstracts away the fact that the 32 bit code uses the 8087 unit with its 16 bit control state, and the 64 bit code uses the SSE unit with its 32 bit control state.

Now your function becomes:

```
function PtCreateADOObject(const ClassID: TGUID): IUnknown;
var
  Status: HResult;
  FPControlState: TFPControlState;
begin
  FPControlState := GetFPControlState;
  Status := CoCreateInstance(
    CLASS_Recordset,
    nil,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    IUnknown,
    Result
  );
  SetFPControlState(FPControlState);
  OleCheck(Status);
end;
```

There are a number of benefits to this approach. Most clearly:

1. You avoid using assembler code altogether.
2. You use the standard RTL units for manipulating the floating point control state.
3. You keep the conditional code confined to low-level routines. High level routines can remain ignorant of that detail and you can re-use this approach in different places at the high level without polluting it with conditionals.

Comment: I copied CreateADOObject from Data.Win.ADODB.pas (XE6), they don't save FPU state in x64 mode, so i think it is ok. To be honest, i have no ideas why they use it for x32 mode, maybe ADO recordset initialization code may change (under some conditions) FPU settings. But GetFPControlState/SetFPControlState is good way to avoid of ASM at all.

Comment: @Andrei The thing is that you've no real control over the code on the other side of `CoCreateInstance`. If it involves a DLL load, which is likely does, that often results in FP control state initialisation. This sort of coding is defensive. See countless posts about Delphi apps, designed to be run with FP exceptions unmasked, being afflicted by third party libraries masking them. There's certainly no harm in doing the same in x64 and the code is just soooo much nicer.