# Enumerate Local Microsoft SQL database servers on the local computer, using Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I am currently using the code within [Enumerate Microsoft SQL database servers on the local network, using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609728/enumerate-microsoft-sql-database-servers-on-the-local-network-using-delphi) which works well. However, I have a need to return only local SQL Server instances. Is there a way to obtain only Local SQL Server instances within Delphi?

Comment: You can use WMI, or you can read it from the registry.

Comment: @JerryDodge -- in local Windows registry informaiton only about LOCAL server running only on LOCAL PC, not accross network.

Comment: @Zam Yes, that's what OP is looking for. "Is there a way to obtain only **Local** SQL Server instances within Delphi?"

Comment: @JerryDodge "Enumerate Local Microsoft SQL database servers **on the local network**, using Delphi" - the title of the question.

Comment: @TOndrej Indeed, the title and the actual question contradict each other. I was trusting the actual content of the question, the part that has the question mark at the end.

Comment: @Zam - indeed the title was in error and has been corrected. Thanks for finding that and allowing me to correct it.

Comment: In the end I used the registry settings; it was the most reliable method in my circumstances. @JerryDodge As far as being a duplicate, I was originally expecting some Delphi code which the other question would not have addressed.

Comment: @JerryDodge if you care to write an answer with the information in your first comment I'll mark it as the answer. If not, no problem's there either.